# Not sure why this error is being thrown: Expected identifier

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular-cli, polyfills

I am working to create an Angular 6 application. Locally everything works great. I hosted the site. I had a friend check on their end if the application works, and it does. No error or anything. On my end I am getting errors in `bootstrap, polyfills.js, vendor.js,` and `main.js`.

bootstrap(141,1) error: 
`Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'`

vendor.js(258,13) and polyfills.js(7442,5) all have the error: 
`Expected identifier, string or number`

main.js(1151,6): 
`Expected identifier`

But I believe all issues are rooted with main.js

The code snippet from the error `main.js`

```
if (_environments_environment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["environment"].production) {
    Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["enableProdMode"])();
}
Object(_angular_platform_browser_dynamic__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["platformBrowserDynamic"])().bootstrapModule(_app_app_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["AppModule"])
    .catch(function (err) { return console.error(err); });


/***/ }),
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IdmStatus</title>
  <base href="/"> 

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

The error is pointing at the `.catch` line.

I'm not sure what would be causing this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you mind sharing the part of your html where the libraries are being loaded? The errors resemble one I got when the polyfills were not loaded before main.js is loaded. And also, what browser are you testing on? `Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'` is an error I used to get before I transpiled my ES6 to ES5 js.

Comment: I am using IE 11 in order to test. I added my index.html above

Comment: Ok I see what's going on. You should load your polyfills in the <head> section. Or if you prefer it to be before the closing <body> tag, make the polyfill load first before your runtime.

Comment: How to do that? I mean it is loading automatically while running the project. How can I achieve what you are saying about loading polyfill in angular 8? @IskandarReza